# Word for "first place something was used"?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

Both of these sentences use one word to describe Example Inc. as particularly important or prominent:

> Example Inc. is the flagship installation of The Amazing Product.
>
> Example Inc. is the premiere installation of The Amazing Product.

But never mind important: how can I say that it's the ***first***?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  `... is the first installation ...`

Comment: I'm certain there's a single word for that, though, that would be used in the same way "flagship" would be.

Answer (score 1):

Example Inc. is the initial installation of The Amazing Product.

Answer (score -1):

"The chief/major installation" would work quite well and be understood by all.